# NDSolve giving NDSolve::deqn: message when given my system of equations

Tags: differential-equations

I am so new on *Mathematica*. I hope my question is suitable. I have looked the Documentation Center and looked also on StackExchange but I could not handle the problem. It gives always the error

> NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of False in the first argument.

My system is as follows;

```
dec = c'[t] == -σ c[t] (α k[t]^(α - 1) s[t]^β - ρ);
dek = k'[t] == -(k[t]^α s[t]^β - (ϕ s[t]^2 s[t])/2 - c[t]);
des = s'[t] == -(-s[t]);
dep = p'[t] == -((p[t] - (ϕ s[t]^2)/2) α k[t]^(α - 1) s[t]^β);
```

For calibration

```
Clear[α, β, ϕ, σ, ρ, δ, a];
α = 0.3; σ = 1; ρ = 0.04; δ = 0.02; ϕ = 0.0003; β = 0.1; a = 0.2;
```

Finally I write

```
sol1 = 
  NDSolve[{dec, dek, des, dep, c[0] == 1, k[0] == 1, s[0] == 1, p[0] == 1}, 
    {c[t], k[t], s[t], p[t]}, {t, 0, 255}]
```

Whatever I have tried, it gives always the following error message quoted above.

P.S. Thanks for your colloboration and sorry for the bad coding.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Actually, your code as posted works fine.  Probably, you neglected to `Clear` some old definition.  Close Mathematica, restart it, and copy the code from your question, and you will see that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace c[t],k[t],s[t],p[t] for c,k,s,p

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{dec, dek, des, dep, c[0] == 1, k[0] == 1, s[0] == 1, 
p[0] == 1}, {c, k, s, p}, {t, 0, 255}];
Plot[# /. sol1, {t, 0, 10}] & /@ {c[t], k[t], s[t], p[t]}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there any precise reason for this change ? Because, in many other codes, people write c[t],k[t],s[t],p[t] for c,k,s,p

Comment: @user1905 No there is no reason.  In fact, your original code works fine.  Either form works.

Answer (score 4):

Your code works fine with a clean kernel. That indicates that previous assignments to `c`, `k`, `s`, and `p` are interfering with your evaluation of `NDSolve`. So you should evaluate `Clear[c, k, s, p];` before evaluating `NDSolve`. The main difference between your `NDSolve` expression and Zviovich's is yours returns interpolating function expressions and his the actual interpolating functions. The difference may seem subtle to you, but it is important. If you want the interpolation functions assigned to the variables `c`, `k`, `s`, and `p`, they are a little easier to extract with Zviovich's form.

```
α = 0.3; σ = 1; ρ = 0.04; δ = 0.02; ϕ = 0.0003; β = 0.1; a = 0.2;
dec = c'[t] == -σ c[t] (α k[t]^(α - 1) s[t]^β - ρ);
dek = k'[t] == -(k[t]^α s[t]^β - (ϕ s[t]^2 s[t])/2 -c[t]);
des = s'[t] == -(-s[t]);
dep = p'[t] == -((p[t] - (ϕ s[t]^2)/2) α k[t]^(α - 1) s[t]^β);
```

Your form

```
Clear[c, k, s, p];
sol1 = 
  NDSolve[{dec, dek, des, dep, 
    c[0] == 1, k[0] == 1, s[0] == 1, p[0] == 1}, 
    {c[t], k[t], s[t], p[t]}, {t, 0, 255}]
```

[image: sol1]

The extraction of the interpolation functions is done with

```
{c, k, s, p} = Head /@ sol1[[1, All, 2]];
```

Now `c`, `k`, `s`, and `p` can be used like any other *Mathematica* functions.

Zviovich's form

```
Clear[c, k, s, p];
sol2 = 
  NDSolve[{dec, dek, des, dep, 
    c[0] == 1, k[0] == 1, s[0] == 1, p[0] == 1}, 
    {c, k, s, p}, {t, 0, 255}]
```

[image: sol2]

The extraction dispenses with `Head` and `Map` and is a little simpler.

```
{c, k, s, p} = sol2[[1, All, 2]];
```