# NDSolve error with a given system of equation

Tags: differential-equations

I know that my question will be very similar to [NDSolve giving NDSolve::deqn: message when given my system of equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89122/ndsolve-giving-ndsolvedeqn-message-when-given-my-system-of-equations) . Sorry for that, I am so new on *Mathematica*. I have tried to use the suggestions from the answers but the system does not work and gives the same error whatever I try.

> NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of False in the first argument.

My code is

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Off[General::spell];
Off[General::spell1];
```

My calibration is

```
paramFinal = {σ -> 1.8, α -> 0.5, β -> 0.3, ρ -> 0.01};
{gsteady} = {0.55};
```

The differential system is

```
dec = c'[t] == -((1 - σ)/(2 σ -  1) (n[t] + n[t]/c[t] β k[t]^α l[t]^β - ρ) - (1 - σ)/(2 σ -1)n[t] + (1 - σ)/(2 σ - 1) (α k[t]^(α - 1)l[t]^β - ρ) - gsteady c[t]);
den = n'[t] == -(((1 - σ)^2/(σ (2 σ - 1)) + 1/σ) (n[t] +  n[t]/c[t] β k[t]^α l[t]^β - ρ) + (1 - σ)^2/(σ (2 σ - 1)) (α k[t]^(α - 1) l[t]^β - ρ) - 1/σ n[t]);
dek = k'[t] == -(k[t]^α l[t]^β - c[t]/k[t] - gsteady k[t]);
del = l'[t] == -( n [t] l[t] - n0 l[t]);
```

I use the following command as suggested in the given answer

```
Clear[c, k, n, l];
sol1 = 
  NDSolve[
    {dec, dek, den, del, c[0] == 0.37, k[0] == 1, n[0] == 0.91, l[0] == 1}, 
    {c, k, n, l}, {t, 0, 255}]
```

I can not figure out why I get the error message. Any hints or suggestions ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The equations you feed in should have double-equals signs `==` rather than single equals signs.  For example, the first one should be `dec = c'[t] == -((1 - \[Sigma])/(2 \[Sigma] -  1) ... `

Comment: @MichaelSeifert it gives the same error when I use double equal signs. I suppose that this does matter in recent versions of Mathematica. (I am not sure)

Comment: I don't get the same error message when I correct the equations;  I get a different one saying that "non-numerical values were encountered", which is perfectly natural since you haven't specified alpha, beta, sigma, rho, or `gsteady`.  You do have one other minor typo, BTW;  there's a backslash in front of one of the sigmas in your expression for `den` that shouldn't be there.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert thanks for your help. I edited the question with the calibration that I use. I think there is a little technical detail that I miss.

Comment: You need to specify `n0` as well.  Once that's done, the code runs just fine (up to $t = 14.1$, but that appears to be a problem with the equations, not the code.)  Also, I assume you mean `{c, k, n, l}` for the equations being solved, not `{c, k, s, p}`.  (The code still works with either version.)

Comment: 1) Your system of ODE are defined for functions `c, n, k, l`, but your `NDSolve` asks for solutions for functions `c, k, s, p`. 2) You still have `dec = c'[t] = ...` when you have `dec = c'[t] == ...`

Comment: @m_goldberg ah. sorry for that but my error continues strangely even when I change it to **c, k, n, l** .

Comment: And have you corrected the bad definitions of `dec, den, dek, del`?

Comment: @m_goldberg yes, if you mean double-equal signs.

Comment: Those corrections have not been made in your question. Also, did fix your `Clear[c, k, s,  p];` as well?

Comment: With all the corrections in place and `n0 = .001`, I get a perfectly good solution to your system of equations. I think your problem was/is bad syntax, typos, and a dirty kernel.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks for your help. I think something very little is missing to me. Because it is something that I use always.